# Pass error message from controller to view in zf2

Tags: zend-framework2

I have simple login in zf2. I want to show error message error to user when username/password didn't match.

In view/login.php:

```
    if (isset($error_msg))
    {
    echo $error_msg;
    }
```

In Controller I have:

```
$msg = array('error_msg' => 'Invalid Username or Password');
return $this->redirect()->toRoute('login', $msg);
```

Here error_msg cannot passed to view, what are wrong with this?

Furthermore I also try

```
$model = new ViewModel(array(
    'error_msg' => 'Wrong username or password',
));
$model->setTemplate('login/index');  
return $model;
```

But here link didn't go to login/index. but instead go to login/process. Process is the action in which login is processed.

Help me friends please. I want to pass error message from controller to view . So how should I do it.

Comment: You don't need a redirect for this. Just use the current view to render the error.

Comment: So, how? code please

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just put your login process code into your login index action, there's no need to have two actions for this.  When you have processed your login and determined that it has failed simply pass your error message to your view model and display it in your view.  This can be done in several ways.

```
$viewModel = new ViewModel();
$viewModel->error_msg = 'Wrong username or password';
return $viewModel;

return new ViewModel(array(
    'error_msg' => 'Wrong username or password',
));
```

or simply

```
return array(
    'error_msg' => 'Wrong username or password',
);
```

Comment: Ayaz, if the problem is resolved with this answer please mark it as correct.