# How to get GET and POST parameters in view in Zend Framework 3?

Tags: zend-framework3

I'm using ZF3, I know the below works in controllers:

```
$this->params()->fromQuery('my_get_var', 'default_value');
$this->params()->fromPost('my_post_var', 'default_value');
```

How to get these **in views**? (of course, without accessing superglobals $_GET and $_POST directly)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that it is the same as ZF2, passing them to the view.

```
    $viewModel = new ViewModel();
    $viewModel->my_get_var = $this->params()->fromQuery('my_get_var', 'default_value');
    $viewModel->my_post_var = $this->params()->fromPost('my_post_var', 'default_value');
    return $viewModel;
```

You can then display them in your view.phtml

```
<?php echo $this->my_get_var; ?>
<?php echo $this->my_post_var; ?>
```

See my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42318604/pass-error-message-from-controller-to-view-in-zf2/42326197#42326197).

Comment: I thought maybe there is a different way, but I guess that's how to should be done

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative way of returning and accessing you could use the provided "Zend magic".

In a Controller, return as so:

```
return [
    'getName' => $this->params()->fromQuery('get_var', null),
    'postName' => $this->params()->fromPost('post_var', null),
];
```

The magic here is that a `ViewModel` is automagically created for you. The second piece of magic is that the returned keys are set as variables in the newly created `ViewModel`.

(edit: just spotted [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42318604/pass-error-message-from-controller-to-view-in-zf2/42326197#42326197) provided by @Garry in his answer which already contains the above)

In the `ViewModel` you could also make use of some of the Zend Framework magic. You could use `$getName` and `$postName` instead of `$this->getName`/`$this->postName`. So, to print do:

```
<?= $getName ?: 'No GET params given' ?>
<?= $postName ?: 'No POST params given' ?>
```